# Trying to copy text from e-mail

Tags: lotus-notes

I am having many issues with IBM Notes e-mail.  When I highlight to copy text from an e-mail I received, instead of copying the text it generates a new e-mail to myself.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Haven't used the software but How can highlighting text cause a new email to be generated, that makes no sense. What if you highlight with shift and arrow keys, that can't possibly cause that..  You could use screencast / screencast-o-matic  https://screencast-o-matic.com  to demonstrate.

Comment: Have you asked your IT staff about this?

Answer (score 0):

To copy, highlight the text either with the mouse or holding down shift and moving the cursor keys. Press Control and C together to copy the text, and then Control and V to paste into wherever you need it.